# '[ERROR] Connection failed: could not find driver' when using OctoberCMS with Laradoc & MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, laravel, octobercms, laradock

I am trying to use OctoberCMS with Laradoc and MSSQL as the database

I have

1. Cloned laradoc into my project
2. Set up the laradoc .env to use php v8.1
3. Run `docker-compose up -d nginx mssql`
4. Entered the container and run `php artisan october:install`
5. Followed the steps

When it gets to the point of creating the database, I get `[ERROR] Connection failed: could not find driver`

I am not sure how to proceed

These are the settings in my octoberCMS .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=mssql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mssql
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using SQL Server here? Port 3306 is MySQL's default port, and `root` the default administrator (SQL Server runs on port 1433 by default, and the default administrator is `sa`).

Comment: @Larnu, I was missing the mssql extention in php, I have installed that, now I get a db timeout whenever I try to install october. In the laradocs .env I found this settings ```MSSQL_DATABASE=mssql
MSSQL_PASSWORD="mssql"
MSSQL_PORT=1433``` but they dont seem to work, and seem to be missing something, like username, I tried filling those in but still get a timeout ```MSSQL_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
MSSQL_HOST=mssql
MSSQL_PORT=1433
MSSQL_DATABASE=mssql
MSSQL_USERNAME=root
MSSQL_PASSWORD="mssql"```